# Question about the logic of flag setting in assembly language

Tags: assembly, arm

Given codes in C
for example

```
if a>b
  c=a+b+10
else
  c=b-a
```

My code in assembly language without using branch:

```
ADR R0,a
ADR R1,b
ADR R2,c
LDR R0,[R0]
LDR R1,[R1]

CMP R0,R1
ADDGT R0,R0,R1
ADDGT R0,#10
STRGT R0,[R2]

SUBLE R1,R1,R0
STRLE R1,[R2]
```

assume, R0>R1, so flags were set at CMP lines

ADDGT and STRGT will run due to the flags. What if ADDGT R0,R0,R1 has a value that will change the flag(Maybe cause V=1) . we didnt do 'ADDGTS' here so next ADDGT can run but wouldnt if affect the actual value of R0??

Thanks

Comment: _"but wouldnt if affect the actual value of R0?"_ Sure. But the `LE` "path" won't be executed if the `GT` path is executed, so it doesn't really matter that you're modifying `R0`. Unless you need the old value right after the code that you've shown us.

Comment: without the S as written those three instructions will either all execute (and all modify R0) or not.  likewise the other two will either run and modify/use r1 or not.

Comment: if you put the S in ADDSGT or ADDGTS depending on the assembler can/will change the flags that affect the next instruction.  as documented in the arm architectural reference manual(s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [ARM®v7-M Architecture Reference Manual](https://static.docs.arm.com/ddi0403/e/DDI0403E_B_armv7m_arm.pdf) (these instructions were available all the way back to ARM 1).

§A4.4.1 *In addition to placing a result in the destination register, these instructions can optionally* [using the 'S' postfix] *set the condition code flags according to the result of the operation. If an instruction does not set a flag, the existing value of that flag, from a previous instruction, is preserved.*

Here you have chosen not to set the condition code register, so the two conditional paths are entirely separate from one another, and the operations in each conditional path won't affect the value of the condition register.

The condition code registers are orthogonal to the operation of the ALU - it might only matter if you wanted to do a 64-bit add or subtract, in which case you might care about the o`V`erflow or `C`arry flags.

Your assembler code seems to agree with the pseudocode.

Comment: it appears that flags are only used for conditioning ?  We were taught that flags are important for the compiler to understand the true value of the register.  Correct me if i am wrong. Are you suggesting that: the flags were only needed to set at 'CMP' so it controls the 'if else' statements.  without setting flags for R0, the correct results of R0 will still be stored?

Comment: Some ALU instructions do indeed make use of condition code flags  for instance, `ADC` - which is add with carry.  shifts can also set the carry flag.  §See A2.5.2.  None of the arithmetic instructions in the code above interact with the condition code register.